# How to find country using IP address in PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I have IP ranges of the country. And I am checking the the user IP address within this ranges if true then he is able to see the site otherwise he wont.
I have use following code,

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   if(ip2long($ip) >= $ipstart && ip2long($ip) <= $ipend){
        return true;
    }
```

My question is that if somebody comes from different country suppose ABC with his laptop/notebook to another country suppose XYZ then **will above code works?** on the same laptop.

**How will it be possible for the above scenario for ipv4 and ipv6?**

**[EDIT]**

Which IP address `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` fetch, will it be the machine IP or the connection IP, so that we can know that he now in this country?

Thanks

Comment: You will need a 3rd party API for IP country tables to look up from

Comment: use this
$countryName = geoip_country_name_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
PHP built method for finding country name

Comment: [IPLocate.io](https://www.iplocate.io) provides a free API: https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8 - Example in PHP: `$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8')); echo $result->country;` - Disclaimer: I run this service.

Answer (score 6):

**use this API http://ipinfo.io**

```
function ip_details($IPaddress) 
    {
        $json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$IPaddress}");
        $details    = json_decode($json);
        return $details;
    }

    $IPaddress  =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $details    =   ip_details("$IPaddress");

    //echo $details->city;   #Tamilnadu  
    //echo $details->country;  
    //echo $details->org;      
    //echo $details->hostname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Php doesn't have a function for this. You should either build a database or just use an external api to find that out.

http://ip-api.com
Here is a good / free one.
Just parse responses from that one.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](http://techignitors.blogspot.in/2013/12/find-country-name-by-ip-address-in-php_24.html)

you can find country name from ip using this function,

```
function getLocationInfoByIp($ip_addr)
{
    $return_data  = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip_addr));
    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
    {
        $return_data['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
        $return_data['city'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_city;
    }
    return $return_data;
}
```

Pass IP address in this function and you will get country info...

For ip address, you can use one of following address as ip address,

```
$client_ip  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward_ip = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_ip  = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: thanks for reply, I have a question that which IP address $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] fetches machine IP or the connection IP?

Comment: you can see in link that i have attach in my answer...

Comment: I have used the above example, and I am shocked when seen the different results in different devices, Only `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` gives the result. For my desktop pc it gives the country **IN**, In my Mobile with Vodafone SIM it gives **GB** and Using Uninor SIM it gives me **US**

Comment: That is because of different ip addresses...

If you use SIM, your ip would be from any country...there is a big problem in using SIM services...
So don't be shocked..