# How to know if a browser user is from Switzerland in PHP?

Tags: php, locale

Is there a way to determine whether a user has set its locale to Switzerland? I tried

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

but this is only giving me "de" as locale. Is there another way or maybe I did something wrong? Is there a free service for IP checks maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find country using IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878058/how-to-find-country-using-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: This code only checks the language of the browser...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8163-PHP-Get-the-current-user-location-using-codehelper-io.html) php class to get the users location in php.

Once you have the files you can use this code:

```
<?php 
/* 
 * Website http://www.codehelper.io 
 * Author: khoaofgod@yahoo.com 
 * Any bugs, question, please visit our forum at http://www.codehelper.io 
 */ 

// Required Libraries 
require_once("ip.codehelper.io.php"); 
require_once("php_fast_cache.php"); 

// New Class 
$_ip = new ip_codehelper(); 

// Detect Real IP Address & Location 
$real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP(); 
$visitor_location = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address); 

// Output result 
echo $visitor_location['Country']."<br>"; 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($visitor_location);
```